Transpose a dataframe so that each row is represented as a single line with column names followed by their corresponding values
I have a dataframe that looks like the following:
   Col1  Col2  Value
1   X     A     1
2   Y     A     2
3   X     B     3
4   Y     B     4

I want to transpose the data to make it more readable.
I want to change the dataframe to something like this:
    X   Y
A   1   2
B   3   4 


As per the suggested duplicate: df.pivot(index='Col2', columns='Col1', values='Value').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None).
